# How to put images/ charts into table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, chart.js

I am coding in Vue.js and got some charts on my site. And I want to put them into some grid or table.It can be 2:2 or 4:2 and I don't know how.

So far I got this:

```
<template>
      <div>
        <h3>Three charts that you can randomize</h3>
        <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
          <div id="mainDiv"> 
            <div id="divOne" class="boxes"> 
              <bar-chart :chart-data="datacollection1" />
            </div> 
            <div id="divTwo" class="boxes">
              <pie-chart :chart-data="datacollection2"  />
            </div> 
            <div id="divThree" class="boxes">
             <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection3" />
            </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </template> 
     <script>
        THERE ARE SOME CHARTS SCRIPTS
     <script>
<style>
  .boxes{ 
    width:middle; 
    float: left;
  margin-left:18px; 
    } 
    #mainDiv{ 
        width:auto; 
   margin:middle; 
    } 
</style>
```

Can tell me how to put there some grid ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you right, you simply asking how to do a `grid` with 2 elemtents in each `row`. If yes, you can use it like this:

```
<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
</style>
```

And the `html` like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>Chart 1</div>
   <div>Chart 2</div>
   <div>Chart 3</div>
   <div>Chart 4</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: @OutLandishnessSad Fine. Please do not forget to accept the answer, if it solved your problem/request.